# Does fetching embeds through messages from msg.reference.messageID not work?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am coding a discord bot, and I am trying to get the content of embeds through the command user replying to the message and using a prefix. When I try running the command, it says that `fetchedMsg.embeds[0]` isn't a thing. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
if (msg.reference) {
    const fetchedMsg = await msg.channel.messages.fetch(msg.reference.messageID)
    console.log(fetchedMsg)
    console.log(fetchedMsg.embeds[0])
}
```

The error is on the line `console.log(fetchedMsg.embeds[0])`, and looking at the log from the code before it includes `embeds: [ [MessageEmbed] ],`.

The error reads  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`, and when I remove the `[0]`, it's undefined. This whole thing is in a `module.exports.run`, if that helps.

```
module.exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {
    const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
        if (args.length === 5) {
        if (msg.reference) {
            const fetchedMsg = await msg.channel.messages.fetch(await msg.reference.messageID)
            console.log(fetchedMsg)
            console.log(fetchedMsg.embeds[0])
        } 
//do things with fetchedMsg
```

Comment: Please be more specific in your issue and share more info about your code

Comment: It appears this issue isn't just about fetchedMsg.embeds. Logging anything in the code like fetchedMsg.author is logged as "undefined".

Comment: So when you `console.log(fetchedMsg)`, is it `undefined`?

Comment: when I log fetchedMsg, it actually seems to be logging every message sent in that channel, which probably has something to do with ```const fetchedMsg = await msg.channel.messages.fetch(await msg.reference.messageID)
```. When I put in anything else, even nothing, it still logs the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `MessageEmbed()` same as normal `Message` using:

```
const messages = args[0]
        if(!messages) return message.reply("Provide an ID for message.")
        if(isNaN(messages)) return message.reply("Message ID should be 
number, not a letter")

        message.channel.messages.fetch(`${messages}`)
        .then(msg => {
            console.log(msg.content) || console.log(msg.embeds)
        })
```

[You can find more here about fetching a message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch)